# Ignore paths for files and directories that dont exists but also skip if it has an extenshion?

Tags: .htaccess

I have this bit of code in my .htaccess and it works great except when there is a missing .js file or .map file it sends it to my index.php file. What I'm looking to have happen is that if its not a directory and not a file and the request uri is anything but .php then to have it not redirect to index.php

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

The first two should go to index.php and the 3rd should not as its a missing file that does not end in .php

```
/helloworld.php
/hello/world
/assets/js/missingfile.js
```

Comment: Could you please confirm sample of URLs which you are hitting and they are going to index.php? Also confirm if you have other rules also in your file apart from these mentioned ones? Thank you.

Comment: I have updated the question with some example paths

Comment: So you mean anything which is not a page existing should go to index.php correct? But what about `/assets/js/missingfile.js` one? Is this file existing? Kindly do elaborate more on same, thank you.

Comment: The first two urls should go to index.php missingfile.js is missing and should be ignored because its missing and has a file ext